# Error: Execution failed for task ':app:clean'. Unable to delete file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm trying to rebuild my Android Studio Gradle project (containing mostly Kotlin code), but it started to throw an `UnableToDeleteFileException` during the cleaning/rebuilding process:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:clean'.
> Unable to delete file: C:\Users\User\KotlinGameEngine\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.1\jars\classes.jar
```

This started happening after I tried to change my project's package structure. Unfortunately, I did it by renaming and moving the source folders rather than refactoring through Android Studio, which was a bad idea.

I've been searching for a solution to this problem all day, and these are the things I have tried to no avail:

- Doing a Gradle sync;
- Reinstalling Java JRE and Java SDK;
- Reinstalling the latest version of Android Studio (1.4);
- Rolling back to the previous AS version (1.3);
- Invalidating the AS cache and restarting;
- Deleting the `gradle` and `.gradle` directories in the project directory;
- Deleting the `.gradle` directory in my user directory;
- Running `gradlew clean` from the AS terminal;
- Manually copying the sources over to a new project (weird that it somehow persists across projects...)

Things that I've tried with a little success, but only let me perform one more clean and rebuild before the error occurs again:

- Closing AS, manually deleting the build files, and opening it again;
- Killing the `java.exe` process while AS is running (this could technically be done every time, but it's tedious and slows down the build process)

So it seems that compile the Java process may put a lock on the build files for some reason, but it might also be something to do with Kotlin. I have a (more mature) Java Android project that I'm working on, though I can't reproduce this error when cleaning it. It seems to only happen to my Kotlin project.

### Update:

I've found that the problem is being caused by the Kotlin Android plugin. The problem disappears when I remove `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'` from the module's `build.gradle` file and comes back when I reinsert it. Feel free to offer any insight into this.

### Update 2:

The last update isn't the cause. I found that if a project contains a Kotlin file then rebuilding and cleaning fails. It continues to fail, even if all the Kotlin files are removed, until the background Java process is killed, meaning it has some kind of lock on the build files. I submitted a bug here with more details and steps to reproduce the bug: [KT-9440](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-9440)

Comment: invalidate cache and restart studio from file menu.

Comment: I had already tried that, but I tried it again just in case. Still no luck though.

Comment: This kind of issue often occurs to me. if first option did not work then log off from system then start studio after logging in.

Comment: Restarted my PC and the problem still persists. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: I solved it by deleting build folder from Explorer

Answer (score 31, accepted):

After I posted a bug report to the Kotlin bug tracker, I was notified of [Issue 61300](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61300) on the AOSP tracker. That seems to be the cause. Since there's nothing I can do at the moment, I'll mark this question as answered, and I'll update the answer if the bug is fixed.

In the meantime, if you're running Windows, I believe I've found a workaround. You'll need to download [LockHunter](http://lockhunter.com/index.htm) (at your own risk of course), then add the following to your module's `gradle.build` file, replacing the `lockhunter` variable with your path to LockHunter.exe:

```
task clean(type: Exec) {
    ext.lockhunter = '\"C:\\LockHunter.exe\"'
    def buildDir = file(new File("build"))
    commandLine 'cmd', "$lockhunter", '/delete', '/silent', buildDir
}
```

This causes LockHunter to forcefully and silently unlock and delete the build files when the app:clean task runs.

Comment: I solved the clean problem with this but unable to do the same for running the app. Still get the same error. Got any idea; maybe change the clean with something else?

Comment: Error:(21, 0) Declaring custom 'clean' task when using the standard Gradle lifecycle plugins is not allowed.

Answer (score 140):

I killed all the java TM processes in the task manager and it let me to  rebuild

Comment: +1. Zombie Java process was the issue. If you're on Win 10, open Task Manager; look for Java (TM) Platform SE binary; End Task.

Comment: You can use `gradle --stop` to stop any stuck daemons as an alternative.

Comment: Is there some automatic way to kill the processes. I waste so much time by killing it manually in every clean.

Comment: In my case, there was an open Meld (compare and merge tool) that was locking the folder to clean

Comment: in my case i didn't found Java TM so i restarted the windows

Comment: @DasserBasyouni try to kill "OpenJDK Platform binary"

Comment: Close all the windows which are opened except the cmd

Comment: it works for me. I have deleted all running process of JAVA.

Answer (score 123):

If you are using Android Studio 2.0 Beta, this issue might appear (more likely if you are working on NTFS filesystem) and it seems like the "Instant Run" is the culprit. Search for "Instant Run" in settings and uncheck the box.

I have filed an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=202297) on the bug tracker.

Comment: I'm using sshfs. Same issue here. Disabling instant run works for me.

Comment: Yes,DISABLING INSTANT RUN Studio 2.0 beta 7 made resolved this exception

Comment: My Android Studio 2.0 was stuck at refreshing a particular project. I tried everything and accidentally followed this answer & it solved by problem which was different from the question.I was stuck for so long . I wish I could  upvote you more times! Thank you

Comment: This worked for me. In case it helps someone: To disable Instant Run in version 2.1 of Android Studio that's File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run and then un-check the first box "Enable Instant Run...".

Comment: This worked for me, until Android Studio was updated.  For v2.1.2 this is no longer sufficient.  Any additional fixes gratefully received.

Comment: I have found, like some others, that killing java processes works.  Don't kill the first one, it is probably your Android Studio: "ps -All | grep java" and then kill -9 nnnn for the process ids of the second, etc processes.

Comment: I'm using AS v2.1.3. In my case, the "Instant Run" box was already unchecked, so I checked it, applied it, Clean & Rebuid the project (the error was still there) and then unchecked it, applied it, Clean & Rebuid the project and the error was gone.

Comment: Also using AS v2.1.3 and @jose 's solution works here, Win 7, NTFS.

Comment: Instant run was already unchecked for me, as I get the 'can't delete file' error every studio upgrade (this time to 2.3 canary 2). I also had to check it, attempt project run, get error message 'need to install apk 23' (the apk of my test device), cancel the run, uncheck instant run, run project and wait 10 minutes for the gradle build with no error.

Answer (score 54):

Try 
         File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart

This worked for me

Comment: The "Invalidate cache and restart" makes Android studio to stuck in Window 8 PC. I am using Android studio 2.2.2. I can use this feature at all. Anyone has a right solution for this?.

Comment: File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart works but takes so much time it is not OK. The basic problem of Win10 file privileges malfunctions re-arrived for me updating to SDK 27 (I accepted the update message). And after the same update the AS cries for NDK 15 but there is only a NDK14 available, set build gradle compile SDK to 26 and it don't cry. Look like we are in between two generations here?? In Win10 x64 there is also problems with the emulators that need data to be wiped to be reused. Sound like an awful lot of details to fix?

Answer (score 31):

Clean project from Terminal using this command `gradlew clean`.

[image]

Comment: Typing the above command started a download, unpack, and install, which took some time.  After that, this solution worked for me.

Comment: It took 11 minutes for this to complete, but it seems to work.A stitch in time saves nine. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I am on ubuntu i ran the gradlew clean as instructed above but did not worked ..:( .command not found .

Comment: @AbhijitGujar You should try `./gradlew clean` on Ubuntu instead. (It will run the `gradlew` executable from the project directory.)

Comment: `./gradlew clean` did not solve this problem for me. It showed the same error again i.e. "unable to delete directory"

Comment: try using sudo if that is UNIX based system

Comment: It worked for me, but before that, I need to give proper permissions to run ./gradlew, with chmod +x ./gradlew. Using Ubuntu 20.04 and Android version 4.1.1, and gradle version 6.5.

Comment: Cleaning gradle from command line sometimes does the exact operation as you click on Clean Project. So instead, one should try to kill the process which is holding up the build files and preventing its deletion. That way, it gets solved.

Answer (score 26):

I solved with command:

```
taskkill /F /IM java.exe
```

and then:

```
gradle assembleDebug
```

Comment: taskkill /F /IM java.exe  was the solution for me. Thanks!

Comment: great.. worked for me <3

Answer (score 17):

Deleting the directory `intermediates` is a quick fix for problem.

The directory will be rebuilt when the project is rebuilt.

Comment: I've tried to delete the intermediates directory, but Windows tells me I can't delete the directory.  Weird.

Comment: It worked for me on one of the projects but not on another :(

Answer (score 12):

I was facing same issue on Android Studio 2.2 preview 1, solution by @AndresSuarez was correct but for some reasons I couldn't find JAVA TM process in my task manager. So I tried the following solution and it worked -

Open *command prompt* and type `TASKKILL /F /IM java.exe`. This will kill all JAVA TM processes automatically. Now re-compile the app again, it will work.

Additionally, you can create a *.bat* file, add the above code in it and run it every time you face the issue.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and this worked for me:

1. close Android Studio.
2. delete intermediates directory (as long as Android Studio is opened, this directory can't be deleted)
3. open Android Studio again

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem in Android Studio 2.3.

I simply restarted Android Studio and after that I could clean without complaints.

Answer (score 5):

For me, this happened because of an **active debugging process**. So, before cleaning or rebuilding, make sure to kill all active processes. To nail down the success, execute **Invalidate Caches/Restart**.

Answer (score 4):

For me it helps when I `Exit Android Studio`, click one more time `Clean Project` (it appears the same error) and next click `Make Project` - after that of course `Run 'app'` button in Android Studio.

Answer (score 4):

For me, the culprit is **adb** holding onto the apk file since I utilise it to install and start the application on my physical device through command line.

So simply:

> Task Manager > End process **adb.exe**

And then the file is free to be deleted and the project may be cleaned

Answer (score 4):

For my case, I resolve it by -

1. First, close the app if it is running in the emulator.
2. Then run the command `gradle --stop` in the **Terminal** in **Android studio**.
3. Then **clean project** and **rebuild project**

Comment: tnx, that helps
I had two demons run at the same time

Comment: This solution is worked for me. I am on RN and just need to close all device connection before clean build.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this one in my ubuntu like this.

1. Check for the processes running in your system(Ubuntu) like in task manager in windows.

   Ubuntu terminal command to list out all processes running  ----> "gnome-system-monitor"
2. Terminate or end the JAVA and ANDROID processes in the list.
3. Again start the studio and import project.

Its works for me without any problems. Hope this helps...

I thought this is the problem with the process that are already created and Duplicated.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is quite easy.

This is one of the solution which worked for me.

> It might be possible that your project's **app/build/outputs/apk**
>   folder is opened.

so just close this folder and rebuild your project. and it will be solved.

Comment: yes I was having this problem , there was a report file that is saved in build/report/checkstyle.html , closing this file solved my problem , thanks

Answer (score 3):

Find programs who used **app/build/outputs/apk** folder, then just delete folder.

I think Android Studio have to delete old apk folder before rebuilding.

Answer (score 2):

Some times intermediates creates problem so delete it and Rebuild project

OR

simply run cmd command - > gradlew clean

in your project folder in work space   (its work for me)

Answer (score 2):

As [suggested in the bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=202297#c81), uncommenting the line

```
idea.jars.nocopy=false
```

in the `idea.properties` file has solved the issue for me.

Note that this needs to be done every time Android Studio updates.

Answer (score 2):

In Android Studio 3.0, I had the same issue. This fixed it:

1. Close Studio
2. Delete projectRoot/build/ and projectRoot/app/build/
3. Restart Studio

Answer (score 2):

**react native devs**

run

```
sudo cd android && ./gradlew clean
```

and if you want release apk

```
sudo cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Hope it will help someone

Answer (score 2):

i simply run cmd command - > gradlew clean , And it fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

This issue appeared to me in android studio 2.0 stable channel and the solution was due to a problem happened while updating my android studio i solved this by installing a fresh android studio. after deleting all old files for the old installation. and to keep the very nice feature of Instant Run

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing with a local backend (java servlet on local google app engine) the running process blocks some files. So you are not able to live deploy. So in this case you can solve this by stopping the local backend before starting clean or build. You find the option under "Run -> Stop backend".

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, tried multiple ways but the solution worked for me was to delete build folders from /android and /android/app directories.

run `react-native run-android` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by global searching the missing directory in the project. then delete any files containing that keyword. it can clean successfully after I remove all the `build` and `.externalNativeBuild` directories manually.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after moving my project from D: to G: drive
but disk checking solved my issue

I used **chkdsk /f /r /x G:**
**
here some command line switches were used:**

/F Fixes errors on the disk

/R Locates bad sectors and recovers readable information (implies /F)

/X Forces the volume to dismount first if necessary (implies /F) (important)

Note: /X is important because it will dismount the drive and you can manually delete the **build** directory of your project,

now rebuild the project

Comment: This worked. Thank you! :) But it took almost 5 hrs. time to complete.

Answer (score 1):

My Solution for this was very very simple ( if you are using Windows).
1- Close Android Studio.
2- Run Android Studio as Administrator.
3- That is it.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this exact problem for myself.

The problem was that somebody else had created the file so even though I have admin rights on the computer I was unable to make changes to the file or files. You need to go into the properties of the file or folder and change the ownership or add ownership. [This web page](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-files/how-do-i-change-folder-and-file-permissions/465f2b42-63dd-4486-8dd1-c870290efeed)  explains it well step by step what you need to do.

Once I did the above, I found the file in file explorer and manually extracted it. I don't think it's needed in the android studio project if it was trying to delete it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Another application that can be using the resources is apparently Android Studio's Kotlin REPL. I closed that, and then I could build again no problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to remove all the Java services but still it is failing while executing the **gradlew clean build** command from IntelliJ terminal. I even verified the other applications I have opened somewhere the same path which I am trying the delete. But could not find any of such. So, finally restarted the IntelliJ IDE and able to proceed build smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

if you're still having issues then update to the latest version of Android Studio(its 2.1 as of now), might be it was a bug with older version of Android Studio. Its resolved for me now.

Comment: Occurring in 2.2 preview 1 for me, so I don't think it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning the project in Android studio and running again fixed the issue. May be do "Make Project" as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by moving project folder into ext4 partition

Comment: Yeah, I've read elsewhere that the Android Studio/gradle/React Native/packager/watchman system has issues (for some reason) on NTFS file-systems.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Android Studio 3.0 Beta 7. Clean Project, Invalidate caches, restart studio did not work but Updating Kotlin version to 1.1.51 and restart studio solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

the thing that worked for me was to close visual studio code and open it again ...
i guess the apk was folder was opened somewhere in code .... 
so just try it might work for you as well

Answer (score 0):

In my case `node.js` was using some resources in build folder (my app in `reactnative`). So I killed `node.js` and it solved.

Answer (score 0):

simple solution :

in android or any jetbrains products when you click to you will find 'invalidate cache and restart ' click on it and all the problems will be solved

Comment: Well, invalidate cache and restart is just a vague solution to any problem. Instead, one should focus on finding out what is the exact root cause of a problem, rather than compromising your local history of cache.

Answer (score 0):

Though this has already been answered, I came from a non-android project and found this, but it could not solve my issue. If someone does see this error, delete the "build" folder manually through your file manager. For me, this repaired the code failing to compile in Kotlin.

Comment: After you should run gradle build, then gradle clean.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove these files manually

In my case I just removed all `build` directories from project and subprojects

Answer (score 0):

Here in 2022 I having the same `unable to delete file` gradle error while trying to build my android project in react-native. When working on the project on a mac I wasn't getting any issues, but when I switch to Windows my build would fail. I've found cleaning the project often resolve build failures and I'm lazy so I had added npm scripts for cleaning my project for both windows and mac, which was part of my problem.

On macOS my clean script included `watchman watch-del-all` and my Windows did not. Me being me, had totally forgot that I had installed the watchman beta  and  that somehow was why my project was unable to delete.

---

Long story short, if you are using react-native and you get this error `watchman watch-del-all` may help, even on Windows

Answer (score 0):

With React Native the commands `TASKKILL /F /IM java.exe` and `gradlew --stop` not working,  for me the solution was to delete the `node_modules` directory and then run `npm install` and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio > File > Invalidate Caches / Restart.
[image]

Answer (score -3):

Follow these Steps From Build Option tab:
1) Clean Project
2) Rebuild Project
3) Make Project