# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'

Tags: android, compiler-errors

Good day.
After updating google repository in AndroidStudio, I have an issue

```
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
> android/support/v7/cardview/BuildConfig.class
```

I'm trying to exclude group android.support from play-services, it did not help.
When I started my project on another PC I have:

```
> Error:Execution failed for task  ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
> android/support/annotation/AnimRes.class
```

my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ru.alexeyk.myevents"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 16
        versionName "1.121"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile('com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.4.2') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    compile files('libs/sentry-1.1.4.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
    compile 'com.github.machinarius:preferencefragment:0.1.2'
    compile 'com.edmodo:cropper:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.1.1'
    compile 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:4.0.0.Final'
    compile 'com.yandex.android:mobmetricalib:2.00@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

In terminal execute in root project folder:

```
./gradlew clean
```

It helped me.

Comment: I saw this error when migrating my project from Studio 1.5 to 2.0 beta. this got rid of the error for me, then I got a "could not delete classes.jar" which was fixed by this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914499/error-execution-failed-for-task-appclean-unable-to-delete-file and then everything built. thanks!

Comment: @dens14345 what os you use?

Comment: Im using windows 8.1 64 bit, android studio version: 1.5

Comment: @dens14345 try .\gredlew.bat clean

Comment: i tried gradlew clean but it's not working.i get same error. any solution

Comment: NOT Working in my case

Comment: I am getting the error, firebase duplicate entry zzcl.class, and this did not solve my problem. Not complaining, just a heads up if anyone else comes unto this problem

Comment: This obviously isn't a solution to any actual problem.  It's just rebuilding the project.

Comment: he's saying to clean your project. You can use ```gradlew <WHATEVER YOUR COMMAND IS>``` in the terminal tab in Android Studio, or anywhere your gradle wrapper is. If you want ```gradle``` available globally, add it to your path

Answer (score 16):

AndroidStudio **Menu:**

> Build/Clean Project

Update old dependencies

Answer (score 15):

All the above not working for me.. Because I am using **Facebook Ad** dependency..

Incase If anybody using this dependency  **compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.16.0'**

Try this code instead of above

```
compile ('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.16.0'){
exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
```

Comment: Sir, if you are ever in South America you just earned yourself a free beer. My god I hate AS.

Answer (score 9):

Open your system command prompt/terminal -> Go to your Project folder path (root project folder ) -> Execute following command : command :- `gradlew clean` or `./gradlew clean`

Make sure that all your gradle dependencies are of same version. -> Example :- your appcompat and recyclerview dependencies should have same version.

-> Change your gradle dependencies to same version like :-

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
```

-> Rebuild your project and it will work fine.

Comment: In my case I got caught with different versions for google play services and firebase ads. Firebase now falls under the google play services umbrella and therefore has the same version.

Comment: This worked for me. cleaned and changed     `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+' ` to     `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1' ` in apps build.gradle.

Answer (score 6):

**Use project root in terminal** like this:-/Users/rajnish/Desktop/RankProjects/ProjectCloud

After that enter this **command ./gradlew clean**

It will work.

Answer (score 5):

There may be different reason for reported issue, few days back also face this issue 'duplicate jar', after upgrading studio. From all stackoverflow I tried all the suggestion but nothing worked for me.

But this is for sure some duplicate jar is there, For me it was present in one library libs folder as well as project libs folder. So I removed from project libs folder as it was not required here. So be careful while updating the studio, and try to understand all the gradle error.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I was starting to lose hope :)
your answer is the solution for my case

Answer (score 1):

I got this error because I did not have the correct line in my build.gradle. I am using the `org.apache.http.legacy.jar` library, which requires this:

```
android{
   useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

   ...
}
```

So check that you have everything in your gradle file that is required.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by double checking the "libs" directory and removing redundant jars, even though those jars were not manually added in the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

see if their duplicate jars or dependencies your adding remove it and your error will be gone:
Eg:
if you add android:supportv4 jar and also dependency you will get the error so remove the jar error will be gone

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this is by changing the version no of recyleview to recyclerview-v7:24.2.1.
Please check your dependencies and use the proper version number.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was caused by `com.google.android.exoplayer` conflicting with `com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk`.

I fixed the problem by excluding the `exoplayer` library from the `audience-network-sdk` :

```
compile ('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.24.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.exoplayer'
}
```