# Retrofit2 Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I installed retrofit2 in Android Project using following gradle lines;

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4'
```

In the first attempt, the following error is occurred.

[image]

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

After that, I added following line under *defaultConfig*

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

As a result of this, the following error is occured.

[image]

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.class
```

Finally, I tried this ([Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209631/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithjarmergingfordebug)) solution, but the result is same.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. If you exclude the *gson* module from *converter-gson*, It works.

Like this;

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
    compile ('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4'){
        exclude module: 'gson'
    }
}
```