# Execution failed for task Execution failed for task

Tags: android, runtime-error, android-gradle-plugin

Here is mybuild.gradle file    here I added jexcel.jar for my  project after that is shows error

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.web03.bulkmessenger"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

  dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'net.sourceforge.jexcelapi:jxl:2.6.3'
```

}

my error list is given below

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.      
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: jxl/biff/AutoFilter.class
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209631/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithjarmergingfordebug

Comment: I cleaned the project but no change@AmitRanjan

Comment: u r using java 8 or java 7

Comment: remove this line compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

Comment: no use @AmitRanjan