# Gradle Error : duplicate entry: com/android/volley/AuthFailureError.class

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I imported EBS Sdk in my project.Now gradle building is success but while running

```
  Error:Execution failed for task':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/android/volley/AuthFailureError.class**
```

this exception occurs.

The following is the build.gradle of both app and the module
i have searched and tried all the possiblities but i am not getting the result

***app/Build.gradle***

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
       compileSdkVersion 23
      buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
   configurations {
      all*.exclude group: 'com.android.volley', module: 'library-aar-1.0.0'
}
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.app.sanyog'
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 3
    versionName "1.2"
    multiDexEnabled = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
 }
android {
     packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt' // picks the JavaMail license file
    }
 }
   repositories {
       mavenCentral()
    }
 dependencies {

compile project(':EBS')

compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'


compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.1.1"
compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.6'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.0.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.0'
compile 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.1.3'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:2.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.3.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
compile 'javax.mail:mail:1.4.1'
compile files('libs/activation.jar')
compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
compile files('libs/mail.jar')




 }
```

***ebs/build.gradle***

```
  apply plugin: 'android-library'

  dependencies {
       compile files('libs/ebs.jar')
       compile files('libs/volley.jar')

    }

 android {
      compileSdkVersion 19
       buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
  }
 }
```

Comment: Hi @anns-rahim, I am also facing the same issue while building with EBS. Can you please post the solution if you have got?

Answer (score 3):

All you have to is add following lines in yout app:gradle

```
 configurations{
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.volley'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning gradle  run these commands

```
chmod +x gradlew

./gradlew clean
```

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209631/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithjarmergingfordebug)

Comment: i tried gradlew clean in my android terminal still its not working