# Was Enabled multiDexEnabled true ,Found Volley Conflict Error

Tags: android

Faced issue Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/android/volley/AuthFailureError.class,  I was added  multiDexEnbled true in my gradle and also dependencies compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1' again i have facing issue its not working for me. Please help what is the correct solution

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132040/duplicate-entry-com-android-volley-authfailureerror-class-while-compiling-proje), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37203309/gradle-error-duplicate-entry-com-android-volley-authfailureerror-class) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168063/gradle-duplicate-entry-java-util-zip-zipexception)

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `MultiDex.install(this);` in your application class?

```
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

Comment: added but no use still facing same issue

Answer (score -1):

this is work for me if you use any sdk like Payumoney etc.. check thats SDK (payumoney) uses the other version of the volley 
so make sour all the volley dependancies will be same other wise it give you error.. latest dependency of volley is   `compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'` 
if this answare is worked for you please vote my ans

Comment: Sorry my friend, but your "answer" is barely readable. I am not even sure if it is valid. If you want upvotes; then improve your content (dramatically).