# I found this issue when running the app on Kitkat device and Lollipop on other version working fine

Tags: android

> Issue:::
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/android/volley/AuthFailureError.class

This is the app gradle configurations

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}



android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.newspiq.newspiqs"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled = true
        renderscriptTargetApi 18
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/'] } }

    lintOptions {
        // set to true to turn off analysis progress reporting by lint
        quiet true
        // if true, stop the gradle build if errors are found
        abortOnError false
        // if true, only report errors
        ignoreWarnings true
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    dexOptions{
        preDexLibraries=false
    }


}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.23.+'
    compile 'com.afollestad:sectioned-recyclerview:0.2.3'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.jrvansuita:GaussianBlur:+'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.10.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile project(':linkedin-sdk')
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37203309/gradle-error-duplicate-entry-com-android-volley-authfailureerror-class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle Error : duplicate entry: com/android/volley/AuthFailureError.class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37203309/gradle-error-duplicate-entry-com-android-volley-authfailureerror-class)