# Transform Classes with Jar Merging Debug Exception

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have a project and a Library included in it, If I enable instant run it generates an apk and runs on some phones while on others it crashes immediately even before splash.
If I disable Instant Run I get

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/nostra13/universalimageloader/cache/disc/DiscCacheAware.class
```

I can't manage to solve, any help would be appreciated.
Here's my Gradle File:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.ids.aldana"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 22
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}


}

 dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1' //23.4.0
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
compile project(':viewPagerIndicatorLibrary')
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3'
compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
   }
```

My Library Gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 16
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 4
    targetSdkVersion 4
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3'
}
```

Can anybody point out the duplicates and tells me how to remove them?

Comment: Check this link hope this resolve your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37460383/android-project-build-successfully-but-ran-failed-with-error-java-util-zip-zipe/37462369#37462369

Comment: I tried it, it didn't work

Comment: u have dupes somewhere in your dependency graph .. so u need to figure out how to display the full graph ( dependency ) as a way to resolve the dupe class issue

Comment: The dependencies are duplicate so exclude that library see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30648172/gradle-library-duplicates-in-dependencies

Comment: add `universal-image-loader:1.9.5` .Then Clean-rebuild

Comment: you have two `universal-image-loader:1.9.3'` .Remove one (build.gradle)

Comment: the library stopped working and need it, how can I make it take the import from the jar file in the project libs directory

Comment: Please add the full output of `gradle --dependencies -configuration compile`.  This will tell us where the duplicate is so we can exclude it.