# Android Build Issues

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle

I was facing a problem earlier this week.  When I tried to do the Android release build it seemed to show the following error --

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzjm.class

I was wondering how I got this error and how to fix it.  It seems as if the problem was inside the build.gradle files. Here they are --

App Level -

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'



android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.unknown.app"
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 20
        versionName "2.34"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':BaseGameUtils')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.2'
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads'
}

}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here is the top level  --

```
  // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Thanks for all help. I have been having this issue for a little while. I could not find the answer in any other stack overflow questions. Thanks Again.

Comment: Maybe this link might help you >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209631/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithjarmergingfordebug

Comment: I tried it before, though it did not work. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: This error may be occur because you have two the same libs that have the same classes. I think you must remove classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' from you top level build.gradle

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did not work though.  It showed error that classpath was not there.

Comment: why you added twice  `compile project(path: ':BaseGameUtils')` and here too `compile project(':BaseGameUtils')`

Comment: That could be the problem. I must have done it accidentally. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: Still did not work. I switched it to one BaseGameUtils compilation. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if the BaseGameUtils module was causing the problem. I am not sure why but reomving it, and replacing the BaseGameUtils for some reason did the trick, and the error did not show anymore. Thanks for all the help along the way of figuring out the issue.