# Transform Exception thrown even when multidexEnabled

Tags: java, android, exception, android-gradle-plugin, android-volley

I am trying to build a release version of my app in Android Studio, and no matter what I try I get the error message:

> Execution failed for task
>   'app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'. >
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   com/android/volley/Request$Priority.class.

I've enabled multidex, cleaned and rebuilt my app, and nothing is working.
The following is my gradle build:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "carter.streakly"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: maybe a duplicate. try to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209631/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithjarmergingfordebug

Answer (score 0):

In `build.gradle` dependencies you included two libraries:

```
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```

where`com.mcxiaoke.volley` is basically a fork of official Google library, so you should use only one of them. Please also note, that according to the [mcxiaoke/android-volley](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley) `READ.ME` :

> (...) this project is deprecated and no longer being maintained, please use official version from jCenter.
>
> `compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'`