# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug' on changing to different computer

Tags: java, android, git

My project works fine on my Computer1 (a PC) and then I move to the MAC, both with same versions of the Android Studio (2.3 RC), and I get the error below. Exact same project, no change.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/view/GestureDetectorCompat$GestureDetectorCompatImpl.class

How to get to use the project from two different machines? I just try to pull the new code from git each time and run the program.

Update: It works on the PC (that's where I created the project). I then commit and push the code to git repo. Then I go to the Mac, and clone the repo to the Mac and then i get their error.

Comment: Does it work on pc1 if you create a new clone elsewhere and do the same steps as on the Mac?

Comment: Please clean your gradle on your mac,or please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209631/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithjarmergingfordebug