# "duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzqd.class" when using Firebase cloud messaging

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented Firebase cloud messaging into my application and i am getting the following error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.>com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzqd.class
```

My dependencies

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
compile project(':module2')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

If you do need Any thing else tell me i will provide that to.

Comment: Have you tried `multiDexEnabled true` inside `defaultConfig` ? If not then try that.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase can generate DuplicateFileException so you have to add the following inside your app level build.gradle as well. The following block would be added inside the android block just below the buildTypes block.

```
//Add the following block
packagingOptions{
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'

}
```

P.S. This and Michele's answer combined worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
compile project(':module2')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

@Kanver Preet Checkout this link it was already answered here

[Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209631/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithjarmergingfordebug)