# How to resolve duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/actions/ReserveIntents.class

Tags: java, android

I get the following error:Error:`Execution failed for task':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/actions/ReserveIntents.class`

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.XXXXXXXXXXX.XXXXX"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.1"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'com.github.nisrulz:qreader:1.0.6'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
debugCompile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'
compile project(':barcode-android')
compile project(':barcode-core')
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.1'
compile project(':imagepicker')
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.0.1'
compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.1@aar'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
 }
```

**Update:**
Two Jar Files are `org.apache.commons.collections` and `com.google.common`  I checked both are not have ReserveIntent class.But when I removed firebase from gradle everything is working.

Comment: Please list the jar files that you have in the `libs` directory

Comment: I believe that this exception means that you have 2 jars in your dependencies that include the exact same class

Comment: This could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209631/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithjarmergingfordebug

Comment: update my question @NicolasFilotto

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After lot of try I found the approach to fix it .

Step 1: switch to project mode

Step 2: Explore the library which you feel is the reason for duplicate.

In my case I was looking for `com.google.android.gms` with Class `ReserveIntents`

Step 3: Once you find it check the library which can be removed because its feature might be used in other lib.

write below code in app.gradle under android root to remove library

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude  module: 'library name'
}
```

In my case duplicate entry was in play-service-base and play-service-basement.

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude  module: 'play-services-base'
}
```

[image]

Comment: Save me a lot of time. I had exactly the same error on the same place. Thank you!

Comment: Sometimes working on Android feels like dark magic

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Cordova for Android development.
remove
cordova.system.library.1=com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+
from platforms/android/project.properties