# Error while run project

Tags: android, push-notification

Error is Like :

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/iid/zzb$zza$zza.class

I get this error..
My build gradle file is..

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.poonam.chatrbox"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary= true
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.+'
    compile 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.tumblr:jumblr:0.0.11'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0"
    // compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile files('libs/apache-httpcomponents-httpcore.jar')
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-android-2.2.6.jar')
    compile 'com.daksh:loglr:1.1.1'
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.3.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0" is already imported by one of your lib so remove it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209631/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithjarmergingfordebug)