# Run query to get Event count from big query

Tags: android, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I am asking how to run query to get event count from my android application.My app using Firebase realtime database and we linked  firebase analytics to Big query.How to get my custom event count by run query from my android application.or Tell me how to get that count from my android app,i have one field in my application to show that count.

Comment: Have you tried looking at [other similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-bigquery+firebase-analytics)? This kind of question probably already has an answer. You might want to take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Could not reach exact solution,Could you please help me

Comment: Please provide more information about what you have tried so far, e.g. the query you are working on. The [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) topic explains how to ask a good question.

Comment: Hi Elliott,Could you please provide step by step procedure to integrate big query in my android app.Now I know the structure of big query in my app.But in gradle part i failed.I could not move..i am struct in that part.Please help me...what are the things i have to add before query a big query from my android application.

Comment: Maybe you should post a separate question under the `android` tag in that case.

Comment: Ok Elliott, I will post.

Answer (score 0):

Only the data gathered by Analytics will be exported to Big Query once the linkage has been established.

Raw data for event count should be available in the event_dim as per the [Big Query Export Schema](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en&ref_topic=7029512).

Refer to the sample queries for Firebase-Big Query for more details in this [official Google docs](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-analytics-big-query#querying_a_custom_event_parameter).

Comment: Hi AniV..Thank you for your answer,I used these query in my app,but when I tried to give dependency in gradle I showing error,i could not run app.My Error in gradle is       Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/common/annotations/Beta.class

Comment: Did you try the suggestions in the answer of this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209631/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithjarmergingfordebug