# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. > com.android 2

Tags: java, android

I am Getting the error, once I build the code.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v7/widget/DefaultItemAnimator$7.class

**Gradle File Details**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "#######################################################"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    multiDexEnabled true //important
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha8'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

//  Appodeal
compile project(':cheetah-mobile-3.4.7')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.8.0'
```

}

Comment: And where is your **code** and **Gradle File Details**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio **Menu:**

> Build/Clean Project

Update old dependencies

from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33333188/3998402)

and make sure your lib folder doesn't have a duplicate library that already in you `build.gradle`

Answer (score 1):

The default APPODEAL ZIP includes the

```
android-support-v7-recyclerview-23.1.1.jar
```

file. That probably collides with one of your dependencies included in build.gradle.

**Just remove it ** (the required classes will be imported from the other dependency