# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. > zznn.class

Tags: android

I am getting this error also with message:

```
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zznn.class
```

This is my dependencies block of gradle. Please help. I also have my multidexenabled true

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile project(':BaseGameUtils')
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.2'

compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'

compile "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0"
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

What we have to do is to delete the extra package.

According to your question,we must know that which package the `com/google/android/gms/internal/zznn.class` is in.

Then,we will find the package and delete it.

Comment: Please can you specify which package should be removed?

Comment: @AbhinavMasters Add `{
exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}`  after  `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.2'`

Comment: @AbhinavMasters another way to solve it ,you can look at this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209631/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithjarmergingfordebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209631/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithjarmergingfordebug)

Answer (score 0):

According to your log

> com/google/android/gms/internal/zznn.class

duplicated so for that solution you have to remove that class file or exclude that library like

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.2'{exclude
>   module: "moduleToRemove"}

Comment: So can you please help me in specifying which module to remove for this?

Comment: For that you have to get that due to which module this duplicate error occur

Comment: May be this can help try to replace `com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.0.2`  with `compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.0.2'){
exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}`