# Duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/security/ProviderInstaller.class

Tags: android, build, apk

What is this:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/security/ProviderInstaller.class

I got this while trying to build an apk.

Comment: post your gradle file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209631/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithjarmergingfordebug)

Comment: i used the clean function in terminal but no use.
How do I post a gradle file?