# duplicate entry: com/android/volley/Request$Priority.class

Tags: android

I tried lots of solutions but they did not work for me
I face this error when I try to generate app file:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/android/volley/Request$Priority.class

and here is my gradle :

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'  //volley http request library
compile 'com.nightonke:boommenu:2.1.0'            //navigation view
compile 'com.baoyz.pullrefreshlayout:library:1.2.0'            //refresh layout
compile 'com.github.medyo:fancybuttons:1.8.3'     //custom button
compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4' //custom edittext
compile 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.1.0' //custom spinner
compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.android-process-button:library:1.0.0' // progressbar button
compile 'com.alimuzaffar.lib:pinentryedittext:1.3.1'  //pin entry edit text
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.zarinpal:purchase:0.0.3-beta' 
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

compile ('com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:1.1.1'){
    exclude group: 'com.nineoldandroids', module: 'library'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
}

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}

Comment: Do you have any JARs in `libs`? If so, what are they?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209631/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithjarmergingfordebug)

Comment: @CommonsWare No I dont

Comment: @JoshuaDrake unfortunately I could not find a solution there

Comment: I've got same problem i just opened issue in `zarinpal`s git.they're using volley in their lib which is not original 'volley'. did you found any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write this answer for every one who is using "zarinpal".
you should just exclude volley library from "zarinpal library like this:

```
compile ('com.zarinpal:purchase:0.0.3-beta'){
        exclude group: 'com.mcxiaoke.volley', module: 'library'
    } //zarinpal api
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue while making build on Jenkins, weirdly it was working fine on my local machine. After adding below exclude it worked both on local machine and Jenkins.

```
android{
   configurations {
   all*.exclude group: 'com.android.volley'
   }
}
```

I have added configurations block to my app's build.gradle inside android section.

If it matter's Compile SDK version is 22 and Build Tools version is 25.0.0

This worked like a charm.