# Getting run time error while generating apk

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have a problem when I try to generate an apk with Android Studio 2.3

I'm getting an error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/antlr/v4/runtime/ANTLRErrorListener.class

I understand that some of my dependencies must implement the same methods, but I can't figure out which one,

Here are my dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.graphql-java:graphql-java:2016-10-19T14-40-14'
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.12.2'
    compile 'io.fotoapparat.fotoapparat:library:1.4.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Thank you

Comment: execute `gradlew app:dependencies --configuration releaseCompileClasspath` and post output here. Also check, that you use `class App extends MultiDexApplication`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209631/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithjarmergingfordebug)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude the antlr4 in the dependency with:

```
compile('com.graphql-java:graphql-java:2016-10-19T14-40-14') {
   exclude module: 'antlr4'
}
```

You can find the related issues here:

1. https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/issues/225
2. https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/issues/254

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for your answer, It worked but i used 
configurations {
        all*.exclude module: 'antlr4'
    }
because other dependencies had antlr4 too
and it worked !