# Got the error during running time

Tags: android

My gradle file is :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.usmans.videodownloader"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // glide
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.11.0'


    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'

    compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+'

    compile 'com.io.tools.android.ramiloif.folderchooser:folderchooser-dialog:1.0.6'

}
```

I am getting Error at run time

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzpy.class
```

please help me regarding this. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with "getting Error at run time"? It looks like a build error.

Comment: My application build successfully but whenever I build the apk then it gives following error

Comment: please go through this once https://stackoverflow.com/q/33209631/6559031

Comment: Try cleaning the project first, and add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at bottom of gradle file