# Android Studio 2 error :app:compileDebugJavaWithJack

Tags: android-studio

This is the complete error from Android Studio 2.1.1. I know this code compiles because on other PC it does, just not on this one which has Windows 10 x64. All other projects fail with similar result.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJack'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.AssertionError: com.android.jack.library.LibraryIOException: I/O error when accessing file 'I:\Android\KeepVidDownloader\Android\app\build\intermediates\packaged\debug\classes.zip': Failed to delete directory 'C:\Users\BCDIAC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\vfs-1464787788985-0'
```

For Build -> Clean Project I have used the solution from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/32924320/1958032

I think that there could be a similar solution for running/making the app.

How to solve this?

Comment: I had the same errors for a while because in the module settings, the JDK location points to a JDK in version 7. Did you check this option ?

Comment: Yes. I have even tried with several JDK 1.8 update versions with same error as result.

Comment: @CPJ did you find any solution?

Comment: @ShashankSrivastava I haven't found any solution for that. Problem persists with latest release. I have installed linux on other partition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issue is a conflict between antivirus and Android Studio. 
In my case using Avira, Windows 10 and Android Studio 2.2.
I just disabled Avira for the first build and enabled it again when build was complete.
No need to do this every time- only at the first build.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it by  *File->Invalidate Caches and Restart*.