# Compilation exception when Jack is enabled

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-jack-and-jill

I am using Gradle 2.14.1 and Android-Gradle plugin 2.2.3 on Android Studio 2.2.3. in a multi-module app. Enabling Jack throws the following exception (stacktrace included) :

```
Executing tasks: [:MyApp:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.       //disabling CoD does not resolve the issue
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.  //I am unable to disable incremental compilation
:MyApp:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:checkDebugManifest
:MyApp:preInhouseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:libone:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:libone:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:libone:checkReleaseManifest
:libone:prepareReleaseDependencies
:libone:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:libone:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:libone:compileLint UP-TO-DATE
:libone:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:libone:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:libone:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:libone:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:libone:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:libone:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:libone:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:libone:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:libone:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:libone:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:libone:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:libone:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:libone:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:libone:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:libone:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:libone:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:libone:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:libone:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:libone:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:libone:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:libone:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:libone:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:libone:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:libone:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:checkReleaseManifest
:libtwo:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2500Library UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2500Library UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2500Library UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2500Library UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2500Library UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42500Library UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:prepareReleaseDependencies
:libtwo:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:compileLint UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:libtwo:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2500Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72500Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72500Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComAndroidSupportCustomtabs2500Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2500Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComAndroidSupportPercent2500Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72500Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2500Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2500Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2500Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2500Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2500Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42500Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2500Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComAndroidSupportTransition2500Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComCommit451PhotoView124Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk4180Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase940Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement940Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm940Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIid940Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation940Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps940Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks940Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision940Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareComUrbanairshipAndroidUrbanairshipSdk801Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareEcomAndroidConsumerappFacebookUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareEcomAndroidConsumerappLibraryUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareNetDanlewAndroidJoda2943Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareSlyce181Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:prepareDebugDependencies
:MyApp:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:generateDebugBuildConfig
:MyApp:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:generateDebugSources
:MyApp:unzipJacocoAgent UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:transformClassesWithPreJackPackagedLibrariesForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:transformClassesWithPreJackRuntimeLibrariesForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:MyApp:transformJackWithJackForDebug
Incremental mode is disabled due to multi-dex legacy mode

<BUNCH OF WARNINGS>

com.android.jack.api.v01.CompilationException: Failed to compile
    at com.android.jack.api.v01.impl.Api01ConfigImpl$Api01CompilationTaskImpl.run(Api01ConfigImpl.java:144)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.convertByteCodeUsingJackApis(AndroidBuilder.java:1852)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.convertByteCodeUsingJack(AndroidBuilder.java:1679)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.JackTransform.runJack(JackTransform.java:221)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.JackTransform.transform(JackTransform.java:195)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:178)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:174)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:156)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:173)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:245)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:221)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:232)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:99)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:58)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:237)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.android.jack.frontend.FrontendCompilationException: Failed to compile
    at com.android.jack.Jack.buildSession(Jack.java:1053)
    at com.android.jack.Jack.run(Jack.java:540)
    at com.android.jack.api.v01.impl.Api01ConfigImpl$Api01CompilationTaskImpl.run(Api01ConfigImpl.java:124)
    ... 92 more

:MyApp:transformJackWithJackForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':MyApp:transformJackWithJackForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.jack.api.v01.CompilationException: Failed to compile
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':MyApp:transformJackWithJackForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:99)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:58)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:237)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.jack.api.v01.CompilationException: Failed to compile
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:54)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:158)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:173)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:245)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:221)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:232)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.jack.api.v01.CompilationException: Failed to compile
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.JackTransform.transform(JackTransform.java:198)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:178)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:174)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:156)
    ... 78 more
Caused by: com.android.jack.api.v01.CompilationException: Failed to compile
    at com.android.jack.api.v01.impl.Api01ConfigImpl$Api01CompilationTaskImpl.run(Api01ConfigImpl.java:144)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.convertByteCodeUsingJackApis(AndroidBuilder.java:1816)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.convertByteCodeUsingJack(AndroidBuilder.java:1643)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.JackTransform.runJack(JackTransform.java:221)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.JackTransform.transform(JackTransform.java:195)
    ... 81 more
Caused by: com.android.jack.frontend.FrontendCompilationException: Failed to compile
    at com.android.jack.Jack.buildSession(Jack.java:1053)
    at com.android.jack.Jack.run(Jack.java:540)
    at com.android.jack.api.v01.impl.Api01ConfigImpl$Api01CompilationTaskImpl.run(Api01ConfigImpl.java:124)
    ... 85 more
```

I am unable to post build.gradle because of 30K char limit. Can post if requested. compile and build SDK version is 25. multiDexEnabled is true.

Comment: Are you by any chance using butterknife? https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/673

Comment: Sorry, I see they seem to have fixed (or worked around) the issue in Butterknife. But in that issue, you see a link to an issue opened for jack: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=218017 in which the developers say it's working as intended, and it's not supported to use libraries from com.sun.*.    Maybe some other library is doing this?

Comment: @Carmen I don't use butterknife or any other com.sun.* libraries directly. Transitively - maybe yes. But there's no way to determine which library is causing this issue. I have more than 20 libraries in use.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem. I disabled incremental option:

```
 compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    incremental false
   }
```

And I Enabled "Dex In Process" for faster app builds.
Add this line to gradle.properties:

```
   org.gradle.jvmargs = -Xmx5120m
```

Comment: I had the same problem and I solved with the `incremental false`! Could you please explain me what it does?

Answer (score -2):

This issue is a conflict between **antivirus** and Android Studio. In my case using **Avira , Windows Defender** Windows 10 and Android Studio 2.2. You can add android studio process in the **exception list** of either programs.

[Reffer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43201846/3383639)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config?utm_source=android-studio#antivirus-impact