# Linux - Gradle can't delete temporary files and build fails

Tags: linux, gradle, ntfs, android-studio-2.2

When I execute `$ gradle :android:clean` or `$ gradle :android:assembleDebug` I get

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':android:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: Could not delete path '/media/naxa/<NTFS Partition>/<Project Path>/android/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-sk'.
```

I'd like to mention that the project is on an NTFS partition.

I found a workaround, I'm using `--continue` option to ignore build failures. But I want to know why the file can't be removed. Is it blocked by anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Execution failed for task ':app:clean'. Unable to delete file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914499/error-execution-failed-for-task-appclean-unable-to-delete-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue which has been fixed in Studio 2.2 preview 3. You can find more info in this [thread](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=202297).

---

If you are on **Windows** and you see the issue, follow Comment #64:

there is a tool you can use to get a stacktrace of the code that opened the file which is still hold by the process. This is the tool I used to generate the stack trace that was partially fixed.

http://file-leak-detector.kohsuke.org/

you need to run studio with the java agent.

---

If you are on **Linux** and you are using NTFS, uncomment the following property in bin/idea.properties :

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# IDEA can copy library .jar files to prevent their locking.
# By default this behavior is enabled on Windows and disabled on other platforms.
# Uncomment this property to override.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# idea.jars.nocopy=false
```

---

If any of you continue to see this issue using 2.2 Beta or later, please file a new bug.