# Updating to Android Studio 3.0 Canary 2 give build errors

Tags: android, android-studio

Today I updated my Studio to Canary 2 and a strange build error arises:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :multipicker:generateDebugSources, :multipicker:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :multipicker:mockableAndroidJar]
Information:0 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
Error:/home/master/AndroidStudioProjects/Reweyou/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:795 invalid drawable
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 compile failed:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 compile failed:
  aapt2 compile -o /home/master/AndroidStudioProjects/Reweyou/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug /home/master/AndroidStudioProjects/Reweyou/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml
  Issues:
   - ERROR: /home/master/AndroidStudioProjects/Reweyou/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:795 invalid drawable
Information:BUILD FAILED in 11s
```

Comment: Probably handle this in googles bug tracker, issues with nightly builds on some software are probably not very well suited for so.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it probably only describes a bug in a very specific early version of Android studio

Comment: isn't a Android Studio error. Its a Gradle bug

Answer (score 10):

I managed to run Android Studio 3 Canary 2 with Gradle 3.0.0-alpha2 based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44202755/3936723

I use Linux, and for me this solved the problem:

1. Open terminal
2. Type:

   `export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
   sh ./android-studio/bin/studio.sh`

--OLD ANSWER--

It will work in Android Studio 3.0 Canary, if you change Gradle to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
```

I have the same error with `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha2` version, rolling back to previous version of Gradle fix a problem for me.

Unfortunately, with older gradle plugin, I can't use advanced options in Android profiler :(

Comment: Thank you, I did change directly my system settings (KDE neon), in regional settings I had "US" region, and detail settings "off", so it did look ok (also examples at bottom of formatted values did look OK!), but the disabled grayed out details were showing numeric/currency/date... as "Czech republic"... so just for curiosity I enabled details, and switched the numbers to en_us, logout+login, and build works. I'm not even sure, where to start with reporting, "WTF moment" of the month for sure.

Answer (score 0):

The solution has been provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44196672/aapt2-compile-failed-invalid-dimen-on-android-3-0-canary-1).

You need to change your PC regional format for numbers to one that use the dot as decimal mark, like English US / UK.

Answer (score -3):

Android Studio Canary 2 changes Gradle to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha2`

A workaround is set back to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha1`

Comment: I tried above changes but still it gave error of not found gradle version etc,....finally I reverted back my studio to canary1...

Comment: it doesn't work