# Android Studio 3.0, AAPT2 compile failed - invalid dimen in resource file

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, aapt

I'm using Android Studio 3.0 Canary 3 on Arch Linux and I am playing around with it trying to make a small app.
Made some research before posting the question but none of the solutions I found doesn't work for me.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 compile failed:
  aapt2 compile -o /home/xhensi/AndroidStudioProjects/FindRestaurant/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug /home/xhensi/AndroidStudioProjects/FindRestaurant/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml
  Issues:
   - ERROR: /home/xhensi/AndroidStudioProjects/FindRestaurant/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:244 invalid dimen
   - ERROR: /home/xhensi/AndroidStudioProjects/FindRestaurant/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:245 invalid dimen
   - ERROR: /home/xhensi/AndroidStudioProjects/FindRestaurant/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:283 invalid dimen
   - ERROR: /home/xhensi/AndroidStudioProjects/FindRestaurant/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:309 invalid dimen
   - ERROR: /home/xhensi/AndroidStudioProjects/FindRestaurant/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:310 invalid dimen
   - ERROR: /home/xhensi/AndroidStudioProjects/FindRestaurant/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:312 invalid dimen
   - ERROR: /home/xhensi/AndroidStudioProjects/FindRestaurant/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:313 invalid dimen
   - ERROR: /home/xhensi/AndroidStudioProjects/FindRestaurant/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:314 invalid dimen
```

Comment: Still present in Android Studio 3, Canary 5 (Ubuntu).

Comment: And actually this is a dupliacate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44196672/aapt2-compile-failed-invalid-dimen-on-android-3-0-canary-1#44202755 (more and better answers included)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AAPT2 compile failed: invalid dimen on Android 3.0 Canary 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44196672/aapt2-compile-failed-invalid-dimen-on-android-3-0-canary-1)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update:**

I found how to fix this issue. Hope this answer helps others too!

Apparently, my Linux Formats settings were in German `de_DE`. I changed them to `en_US`.
Write these command in your terminal:

`export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"`

`source ~/.bashrc`

Then, in my case, it worked after a system restart (normally it should also work with a log off).

More information about setting:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/724338/how-to-set-lc-numeric-to-english-permanently

Comment: Environment variables, such as LC_NUMERIC, will not be preserved after a restart if you just set them with a command in a terminal. You need to add it to an init file.

Comment: How about on MacOSX?

Comment: Add the line `export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"` into your users shell profile (etc ~/.bashrc). 
It will become available after next restart and login into the users profile. 
Second way to make the variable LC_NUMERIC available is to run `source ~/.bashrc` and your current shell profile will be updated