# AAPT2 compile failed: invalid dimen on Android 3.0 Canary 1 on Windows

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, aapt

I have this problem after upgrade AndroidStudio to 3.0 Canary 1

```
Error:D:\Project\Freelance\Andoid\sosokan-android\sosokan-android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:911 invalid drawable
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 compile failed:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 compile failed:
  aapt2 compile -o D:\Project\Freelance\Andoid\sosokan-android\sosokan-android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug D:\Project\Freelance\Andoid\sosokan-android\sosokan-android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
  Issues:
   - ERROR: D:\Project\Freelance\Andoid\sosokan-android\sosokan-android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:911 invalid drawable
```

It look same 
[AAPT2 compile failed: invalid dimen on Android 3.0 Canary 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44196672/aapt2-compile-failed-invalid-dimen-on-android-3-0-canary-1) but I can not find the way to make it work on Window

Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated.

Comment: @pixel please check my question again. I am asking for the solution on Window **not Ubuntu**

Comment: Ok, edtited the post a little

Comment: @PhanVanLinh : Did you get any solution? I am facing same issue.

Comment: @Sonali8890 sorry. I still find solution. if I found I will notify you

Answer (score 9):

did you see this https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/4u0gw1/support_library_2411_released/

If you are using support libraries on version 24.x (you or even your dependencies), this is incompatible with AAPT2 and you should :

- disbale aapt2 in your gradle.properties file
  :`android.enableAapt2=false`
- or upgrade google libraries to version 25
  or 26

Answer (score 4):

@Phan Van Linh, can you please check the line from "values.xml:911" where you are getting the invalid drawable issue & google it exactly?

I had the same issue with one of my project and the problematic line was:

```
<item name="crop_image_menu_crop" type="drawable"/>
```

It was from an [image library](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper) I had used in my project. The issue was that I was using an older version of the library. Once I updated to newer version, the error was gone.

Hopefully, your issue might get fixed like mine.

Happy Hunting!